# Why is the dimension of a kernel with the basis $\{[0,0,0]\}$ equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces

What is the dimension of a kernel with the basis $\{[0,0,0]\}$?

I'm confused because the definition of the dimension is number of vectors in a basis. So there is $1$ vector here which is $[0,0,0]$.

Why does my professor say that the dimension of kernel is zero? He mentioned something about the zero vector space.

Comment: It's not a basis. $\{[0,0,0]\}$ is linearly dependent, since $1\cdot [0,0,0] = [0,0,0]$.

Comment: A basis is a collection of independent vectors, and $[0,0,0]$ is not an independent vector.

Comment: @DanielFischer does that mean its possible to have an empty basis?

Comment: Yes, the unique basis of the trivial vector space (over whichever field) is $\varnothing$. ($\sum\limits_{v\in\varnothing} v = 0$, so it's a generating set.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space *spanned* by $[0,0,0]$ is $\{[0,0,0]\}$, i.e. then null space.

A basis needs to be made of linearly independant vectors, and thus a family which contains the null vector cannot be a basis !

The basis of the null space would just be the empty set $\emptyset$, hence its dimension is $0$

Answer (score 0):

A basis is defined as a set of linearly independent vectors that span a space. For the row space (kernel) of your problem, it clearly only includes the zero vector. However the zero vector, v, is linearly indepedent (as there exists a scalar, C != 0, such that Cv = 0), therefore the basis of the row space has no dimension.

Comment: Has no dimension, or has dimension $0$ ?